# running stored procedures into own model with servicestack ormlite

Tags: servicestack

Is there any examples to be found for running a stored procedure on serviceStack MVC  using ormlite?   mythz ?    seen this block of code:

```
var results = new List<EnergyCompare>
                    {dbFactory.Exec(dbCmd =>
                       {
                          dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                          dbCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", 1));
                          dbCmd.CommandText = "GetAuthorById";
                          return dbCmd.ExecuteReader().ConvertTo<EnergyCompare>();
                       }
                    )};
```

but came with the text of never worked on the google groups!

i can also write this:

```
using(var db = new SwitchWizardDb())
            {
             var results2 = db.dbCmd.ExecuteProcedure()   
            }
```

but not sure how to complete this with parameters, and in the source code I looked at, it said obsolete?

thanks

Comment: I have just run the first procedure example and got no results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I figured it was best to roll my own handler so have created this, any thoughts would be most welcome, especially with how I could pass over params in some kind of func or something:

I have a main class to deal with easy access to my connection object:

```
public class DatabaseNameSp : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SqlConnection _spConn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseNameSp .dbConString);
    public readonly SqlCommand SpCmd;

    public DatabaseNameSp (string procedureName)
    {
       _spConn.Open();

        SpCmd = new SqlCommand
                    {
                        Connection = _spConn,
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                        CommandText = procedureName
                    };
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
         _spConn.Close();
         SpCmd.Dispose();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
using (var db = new DatabaseNameSp ("procedurenname"))
            {
                db.SpCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", 1));

                var rdr = db.SpCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                var results = new List<CustomDTO>();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    results.Add(new CustomDTO { Name = rdr["name"].ToString(), Id = rdr["id"].ToString() });
                }
                return new CustomDTOResponse { Results = results };
            }
```

Any thoughts !

thanks

Comment: any accepted answer deserves an upvote, right? :D just saying

Answer (score 23):

Looks like ServiceStack.ORMLite has been updated to make this easier:

```
List<Poco> results = db.SqlList<Poco>("EXEC GetAnalyticsForWeek 1");
List<Poco> results = db.SqlList<Poco>("EXEC GetAnalyticsForWeek @weekNo", new { weekNo = 1 });

List<int> results = db.SqlList<int>("EXEC GetTotalsForWeek 1");
List<int> results = db.SqlList<int>("EXEC GetTotalsForWeek @weekNo", new { weekNo = 1 });
```

This example is on the [front page of the github repo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#new-apis-to-execute-custom-sql).

Comment: It works, but when I send Nullable DateTimes does it sends NULL to the parameters or DateTime MinValue ? @ZacharyYates

Comment: @RogerOliveira I'm pretty sure it sends NULL, but I haven't tested it

Comment: It does, I did a few tests, but the parameter must be DateTime Nullable otherwise it sends minvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of running a stored procedure with ormLite that may help you:

```
IList<MyDTO> myList = DbFactory.Run(dbCnx =>
{
 using (var dbCmd = dbCnx.CreateCommand())
 {
      dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      dbCmd.CommandText = "mySchema.myStoredProc";
      dbCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1", val1));
      dbCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param2", val2));

      var r = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
      return r.ConvertToList<MyDTO>();
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To just simply run a stored procedure with no data returned:

```
 public class ComsManager : Dbase
 {   
    private IDbConnection dbConn;

    public ComsManager()
    {
        dbConn = Dbase.GetConnection();
    }

    public void Housekeeping()
    {
        using(var dbCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand())
            dbConn.Exec(res => { dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; dbCmd.CommandText = "SP_housekeeping"; dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); });
    }
```